# I have 2 different classes that I want to add to an ArrayList what the best way to define the ArrayList?

Tags: java, object, generics, arraylist

I have class A and class D that depending on the case that I want to add to an ArrayList and later use instanceOf to determine which class is present. I'm not sure whether to use and wildcard generic

```
 private ArrayList<?> mEntity = new ArrayList<>();
```

or define it as an Object

```
 private ArrayList<Object> mEntity = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: If you need to know what is of type ``A`` and what is of type ``D``, keep 2 lists.

Comment: is there a parent type to both A and D, if soo, use that type rather than Object. Also any particular reason you cant maintain 2 arraylists?

Comment: Are the classes A & D inherit the same class?

Comment: Use `<Object>` or whatever other common superclass/interface they share.

Comment: you can't use a wildcard bound in your case, if A and D don't share any other super types `<Object>` will work, you should check out [Angelika Langer's FAQ to TypeArguments](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ203)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct design depends on what you'll do after you take A or D typed objects from the `ArrayList`.

If you're doing completely different things to different A and D objects then there is no functional overlap even if they have common fields. You can still do

```
private ArrayList<Object> mEntity = new ArrayList<>();
```

But that has little help if you will process the object like

```
for (int i=0 ; i < mEntity.size() ; i ++=) {
    Object obj = mEntity.get(i);
    if (obj instanceOf A) {
        // Do Something
    } else if (obj instanceOf D) {
        // Do other things
    }
}
```

Instead of this you can easily use two `ArrayList` objects.

However if you have some common functionality in A and D, and you'll be using the object by this functionality then you can encapsulate this common functionality into an interface.

Assume you'll process the objects like

```
for (int i=0 ; i < mEntity.size() ; i ++=) {
    Object obj = mEntity.get(i);
    if (obj instanceOf A) {
        A objA = (A) obj);
        objA.workerMethod();
    } else if (obj instanceOf D) {
        D objD = (D) obj;
        objD.workerMethod();
    }
}
```

Then you can define an interface and use polymorphism

```
public interface CommonFunc {
    void workerMethod();
}

private ArrayList<CommonFunc> mEntity = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0 ; i < mEntity.size() ; i ++=) {
    CommonFunc obj = mEntity.get(i);
    obj.workerMethod();
}
```

You can do this even if there is no common method but still it has little meaning.